# IP Address Iteration, Why do I not have to nestle 'x' in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, for-loop, iteration

I am completing the python masterclass challenge program 1. I understand everything from the solution until the very last line of code. We have to determine the number of segments and length of segments within a valid/invalid ip address.

I understand that this will accurately display the number of segments and length of segments, but why doesn't the final line have to be nestled in a for loop? How can I just call an arbitrary 'x' from thin air? It is not in reference to any variable or str? I'm trying to understand the thought process of the system.

My code is as follows:

```
ip=input('Please enter your ip address.')
numsegment = 1
lensegment = 0

for x in ip:
    if x == '.':
        print('Segment {} contains {} 
characters.'.format(numsegment,lensegment))
        numsegment+=1
        lensegment=0
    else:
        lensegment+=1

if x != '.':
    print('Segment {} contains {} characters.'.format(numsegment,lensegment))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `for` loops use assignment. This has some side effects, one of them is that the name used for the iteration will store the value it had during the last iteration even after the loop block is exited.

```
for num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    pass

print(num)
#  5
```